# Python get text from 3d image

Tags: python

I have a 3d image .I want to extract the text which is written on the image. I tried it using matplotlib but this library is used only for plotting images, not for extracting texts from images. Plz help

Comment: Can you post some sample images?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried [pytesser](http://code.google.com/p/pytesser/) or [ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/). They are very efficient optical character recognition tools.

Comment: Yes i have tried them. They are for 2d images only but i want to extract text from a 3d image.

Comment: You can get the image here
 (http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://static.raymond.cc/images/teabag-3d-captcha.png&imgrefurl=http://www.raymond.cc/blog/5-tools-to-automate-rapidshare-downloading-for-free-users-with-no-captcha/&usg=__Ts1B8DuvpExGDyyYlXfpcnbkif4=&h=164&w=314&sz=7&hl=en&start=5&sig2=-IyOG8AzkwebHXFv0g4PrA&zoom=1&tbnid=u7IHcCUEE7eLcM:&tbnh=61&tbnw=117&ei=KLknUMqDJJHRrQfbxoHQBA&um=1&itbs=1)